# Projected gradient descent in keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow, gradient-descent, pytorch

I am currently working on a project and I need to do projected gradient descent instead of vanilla gradient descent on a network. I am unsure if current deep learning frameworks have that functionality. I tried searching online but didn't get much. Any help in this regard is appreciated!